# Is there an objective-c/iPhone version of currentTimeMillis() from Java?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to time some events in the app I'm working on. In Java i used to be able to call currentTimeMillis() but there doesnt seem to be a version in Objective-c. Is there a way to check there current time without creating a NSDate and then parsing this object everytime i need this information?

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's also `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`, which will give you the time in double-precision seconds.

Answer (score 13):

`[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000` returns a the same value as `currentTimeMillis()`

`CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()` and `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` both return a double starting at Jan 1 2001 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: Not really. `timeIntervalSince1970` returns the time in seconds, while the name `currentTimeMillis()` implies that it returns milliseconds.

Answer (score 7):

To get very cheap very precise time, you can use [`gettimeofday()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), which is a C Function of the BSD kernel. Please read the man page for full details, but here's an simple example:

```
struct timeval t;
gettimeofday(&t, NULL);

long msec = t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;
```

Comment: Right, this is cheaper than `[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000`. It return interval from midnight (0 hour) 1/1/1970. 

You should use `gettimeofday(&t, NULL);` if your code is called very often like update loop on game.

You'd beter use long long data type for this big value:
`long long millis = t.tv_sec * 1000 + t.tv_usec / 1000;`

Answer (score 2):

Instead `gettimeofday()` you could also use `[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` (the class method) and do your calculations with that. But they have the same problem: they operate on "wall clock time". That means your measurement can be off if leap seconds are added while your test is running or at the transition between daylight saving time.

You can use the Mach system call `mach_absolute_time()` on OS X and iOS. With the information returned by `mach_timebase_info()` this can be converted to nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; this will give you current timestamp in milliseconds.

The answer given by @Noah Witherspoon returns current date but the year is not the current matching year.